# Cygwin - cd in bash script

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm new to using Cygwin, so apologies if this is a very newbie question.

I have a bash script where I "cd" to a directory then do something in that directory. However, the cd command fails with "No such file or directory /c/code/blah/blah".

If I copy the cd line directly into the shell prompt, then it works fine. It just fails in the script.

[edit] As requested, I've added the actual lines from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /c/Code/Project
```

Thankyou for any help with this,
Dan.

Comment: Can you post the actual line(s) from the script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What kind of line endings does your script have? For Cygwin bash script to work properly (without having to set special options), it must have Unix line endings (LF) rather than DOS line endings (CR-LF). If you saved the script with DOS line endings, bash will see your argument to `cd` as `/c/Code/Project^M`, where `^M` is a CR, and won't find a directory by that name.

To see which kind of line endings it has, you can execute `file scriptname`, where *scriptname* is the name of your script. To convert the script so that it has Unix line endings, execute `d2u scriptname`.

Don't use Notepad to edit Cygwin bash scripts. It always saves files with DOS line endings.

Comment: Aha! That was it. I was using Vim to edit it. Thankyou :-)

Comment: Vim will work fine. It automatically detects whether files have Unix or DOS line endings and will save them the same way. By default, Cygwin's vim will create new files with Unix line endings, but Windows' gvim will create new file with DOS line endings. You can change that. See `:help ff` and `:help ffs`.

Comment: Emacs was also saving with CR-LF. Changing the line-ending style in-editor: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineTips

Answer (score 4):

Unless you override, a script executes in its own copy of the shell (usually Bash).  Then when the script exits, that instance of bash also exits.  So your script CDs into a new directory and then exits, returning you to the original Bash--which never did a CD.

Two ways to work around it.  You can use an alias instead of a script, e.g. in your .profile have

```
alias mycd="cd /c/Code/Project"
```

Another way is to tell Bash not to spawn a subshell by using the "dot" syntax

```
. myscript
```

Comment: You've misread my question. The error message I asked about is written to the stdout by the cd command, which is within the script. I'm not asking for the current directory to have been changed once the script exits.

Comment: I had a similar problem to the OP but without error ; this answer helped me a lot, even if it is not "100% on-topic".

Answer (score 2):

You might find your files in /cygdrive/c...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`cd /cygdrive/c/code/blah/blah`

Comment: That will work for `'cd c:/code/blah/blah`' not for `'cd /c/code/blah/blah`'. Also, the '`c:`' form works from a script too; Something else is missing here, the question needs more elaboration.

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: @nik the c: form didn't work either. Nothing I try works from a script. They all work from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment or vote but CarlF's answer helped me.

"So your script CDs into a new directory and then exits, returning you to the original Bash--which never did a CD."

Same script, but in my case, no error message.

This worked for me:

. myscript.sh